# Alert исчезает без участия пользователя

Tags: javascript, alert

Только начинаю изучать верстку вообще и js в частности, скрипт достаточно простой:

```js
'use strict';
alert('Эта страница является тренировочной!\nСодержащийся в ней контент не имеет отношения к действительности!\n\nThis page is just for practice!\nThe content it contains is irrelevant!');

function getCoords(elem) {
  let box = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + pageYOffset;
  return box;
}

let actDotPosicion = 'dot1';
let startActDotPosicion = getCoords(document.getElementById('section1'));

document.getElementById('scroller').onscroll = function() {
  let sectionCoord = getCoords(document.getElementById('section1'));
  if (sectionCoord == startActDotPosicion) {
    let a = document.getElementById('dot1');
    if (a != null) {
      a.src = 'pic/active-dot.png';
      let b = document.getElementById('active-dot');
      b.src = 'pic/dot.png';
      b.id = actDotPosicion;
      actDotPosicion = a.id;
      a.id = 'active-dot';
    };
  } else if (sectionCoord == startActDotPosicion - 365) {
    let a = document.getElementById('dot2');
    a.src = 'pic/active-dot.png';
    let b = document.getElementById('active-dot');
    b.src = 'pic/dot.png';
    b.id = actDotPosicion;
    actDotPosicion = a.id;
    a.id = 'active-dot';
  } else if (sectionCoord == startActDotPosicion - 365 * 2) {
    let a = document.getElementById('dot3');
    a.src = 'pic/active-dot.png';
    let b = document.getElementById('active-dot');
    b.src = 'pic/dot.png';
    b.id = actDotPosicion;
    actDotPosicion = a.id;
    a.id = 'active-dot';
  } else if (sectionCoord == startActDotPosicion - 365 * 3) {
    let a = document.getElementById('dot4');
    a.src = 'pic/active-dot.png';
    let b = document.getElementById('active-dot');
    b.src = 'pic/dot.png';
    b.id = actDotPosicion;
    actDotPosicion = a.id;
    a.id = 'active-dot';
  } else if (sectionCoord == startActDotPosicion - 365 * 4) {
    let a = document.getElementById('dot5');
    a.src = 'pic/active-dot.png';
    let b = document.getElementById('active-dot');
    b.src = 'pic/dot.png';
    b.id = actDotPosicion;
    actDotPosicion = a.id;
    a.id = 'active-dot';
  };
}
```

https://first-lending-l30p0h.netlify.app/ так это на хостинге выглядит.

Так вот, при первой загрузке алерт обычно (но тоже далеко не всегда) появляется и ждет нажатия кнопки, как и должен. А вот после перезагрузки страницы чаще всего он через мгновение исчезает сам. Почему?

Comment: Может иметь отношение: "Under some conditions — for example, when the user switches tabs — the browser may not actually display a dialog, or may not wait for the user to dismiss the dialog." (отсюда: [Window.alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)).

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, попробовал через window - результат не изменился.

Comment: Я имел в виду не добавления `window`, а то, что некоторые браузеры могут сами по себе убирать alert, если посчитают, что он без нужды блокирует страницу.

Comment: И ещё — лучше создавать один вопрос на проблему. Вопросы с несколькими проблемами могут заминусовать или закрыть.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, тогда встает вопрос о критериях, по которым браузеры решают, что алерт зря блокирует страницу, и методах нашего влияние на эти критерии.

Answer (score 1):

если тебе нужен именно stop alert, просто вынеси его в отдельный файл и вставь в конец тега `<head>`, еще почитай про async и defer тут: https://learn.javascript.ru/external-script

Comment: Благодарю, читал об этом уже, даже пробовал defer использовать, но проблему не решало. Насчет "в отдельный скрипт"... Ради одной команды городить скрипт странновато, на мой взгляд. К тому же непонятно, а чем браузеру не нравиться эта команда в начале одного общего скрипта.

Comment: Тем, что рекламщики достали всех с алертами и поэтому браузеры пытаются их блокировать.

Answer (score 0):

Сам спросил, сам ответил.
Решил проблему тем, что вставил алерт прямо в html между head и body. Теперь не закрывается, но это костыль, как по мне. Из внешнего файла оно должно работать точно так же, а этого не происходит и причина неясна.